# send what its capured from a form to the actions file React/Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I want to send that state of a component to the actions file.
My component is a `<form>` where the user can capture some config that later i want to apply that config to the actions file.

Component Code:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';

class AdminConfig extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state=({
      baseURL:'BASE_URL',
      hospitalName: '',
      hospitalExternalID:'1000849',
      payerName:'',
      payerAddress:''
    })
    this.onBaseURLChange = this.onBaseURLChange.bind(this);
    this.onHospitalNameChange = this.onHospitalNameChange.bind(this);
    this.onHospitalExIDChange =  this.onHospitalExIDChange.bind(this);
    this.onPayerNameChange = this.onPayerNameChange.bind(this);
    this.onPayerAddressChange = this.onPayerAddressChange.bind(this);
    this.onAdminFormSubmit = this.onAdminFormSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  onBaseURLChange(e){
    this.setState({
      baseURL: e.target.value
    })
  }
  onHospitalNameChange(e){
    this.setState({
      hospitalName: e.target.value
    })
  }
  onHospitalExIDChange(e){

  }
  onPayerNameChange(e){
    this.setState({
      payerName: e.target.value
    })
  }
  onPayerAddressChange(e){
    this.setState({
      payerAddress: e.target.value
    })
  }
  onAdminFormSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    // here is where i need to send something  like this:
    this.props.fetchAdminConfig(this.state.baseURL)
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div className="container ">
        <form className="admin-form" onSubmit={this.onAdminFormSubmit}>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="jumbotron col-md-12">
              <h4>API CONFIGURATION</h4>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-12">
              <div className="panel panel-primary">
                <div className="panel-heading">BASE URL</div>
                <div className="panel-body">
                  <input
                    onChange={this.onBaseURLChange}
                    type="text"
                    className="form-control"
                    id="baseURL"
                    placeholder="Base URL" />
                  <div className="panel-body" id="getResult">  <p className="">Base URL: http://{this.state.baseURL}/trucare-api-6.2.1.TC621/6.2.1/api</p></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="jumbotron col-md-12">
              <h4>HOSPITAL INFORMATION</h4>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-6">
              <div className="panel panel-primary">
                <div className="panel-heading">Hospital Name</div>
                <div className="panel-body">
                  <input
                    onChange={this.onHospitalNameChange}
                    type="text"
                    className="form-control"
                    id="hospitalName"
                    placeholder="Hospital Name" />
                  <div className="panel-body" id="getResult"><p className="">Hospital name: {this.state.hospitalName}</p></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-6">
              <div className="panel panel-primary">
                <div className="panel-heading">Hospital External ID</div>
                <div className="panel-body">
                  <input
                    onChange={this.onHospitalExIDChange}
                    type="text"
                    className="form-control"
                    id="hospitalEXID"
                    placeholder="Hospital Name" disabled />
                  <div className="panel-body" id="getResult"><p>Hospital External ID: {this.state.hospitalExternalID}</p></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="jumbotron col-md-12">
              <h4>PAYER INFORMATION</h4>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-6">
              <div className="panel panel-primary">
                <div className="panel-heading">Payer Name</div>
                <div className="panel-body">
                  <input
                    onChange={this.onPayerNameChange}
                    type="text"
                    className="form-control"
                    id="payerName"
                    placeholder="Payer Name" />
                  <div className="panel-body" id="getResult"><p>Payer Name: {this.state.payerName}</p></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-6">
              <div className="panel panel-primary">
                <div className="panel-heading">Payer Address</div>
                <div className="panel-body">
                  <input
                    onChange={this.onPayerAddressChange}
                    type="text"
                    className="form-control"
                    id="payerAddress"
                    placeholder="Payer Address" />
                  <div className="panel-body" id="getResult"><p>Payer Address: {this.state.payerAddress}</p></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Apply config</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default AdminConfig
```

Then on my actions file I have this:

```
export function fetchAdminConfig(BASE_URL){
...
}
const BASE_URL = //this is where I want to apply the state that I captued on my form 
    export function fetchUsers() {
      const request = axios.post(`${BASE_URL}/endpoint`)
      return {
        type: FETCH_USERS,
        payload: request
      };
    }
```

How Can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a parameter to your action creator function and pass it in!

```
export function fetchAdminConfig(BASE_URL) {
  const request = axios.post(`${BASE_URL}/endpoint`)
  return {
    type: FETCH_USERS,
    payload: request
  };
}
```

Comment: But Do I need to add something to my component File? I was reading some docs and it says something Like mapDispatchToProps

Comment: Oh.  You need to connect your component to get access to the dispatch function and then you can use mapDispatchToProps to reduce some boilerplate.

Comment: Can you explain that on you answer with more details on how to